# Making export default work with Babel, webpack and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work.

I am building a ES6 style class and want to export it to be able to use it somewhere else in the server side. I put the code into a file called `PlayerManager.js`in the `server` folder.

I put my client code in the `src` folder. And my server code in my `server` folder and `server.js` outside of `server` folder.

Here is the directory structure:

```
Root
 - dist
 - node_modules
 - public
 - server
 - src
 server.js
 webpack.base.js
 webpack.dist.js
 package.json
 .babelrc
```

`PlayerManager.js` file:

```
class PlayerManager {

    constructor() {
        if (! PlayerManager.instance) {
            this.playerList = {};
            this.bulletList = {};
            this.initPack = {player: [], bullet: []};
            this.removePack = {player: [], bullet: []};

            PlayerManager.instance = this;
        }

        return PlayerManager.instance;
    }

    resetData() {
        this.initPack.player = [];
        this.initPack.bullet = [];
        this.removePack.player = [];
        this.removePack.bullet = [];
    }

}

const instance = new PlayerManager();
Object.freeze(instance);

export default instance;
```

However, when I use `npm run dev` which runs `node server.js` it throws an error saying

```
export default instance;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
```

Here is the configuration for babel in webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'public/img',
          to: 'static' },
        { from: 'public' }
      ])
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        //include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        ],
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=90000' } 
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  }
};
```

In `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],

  "sourceRoot": "./src"
}
```

In my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run lint && npm run release",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./src/**/*.js",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "release": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.dist.js --progress",
    "test": "./test/*.test.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive --reporter spec"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is a bundler for producing packages that run on the client (in the browser), it is not aware of or concerned with code on the server. (Unless you are doing universal application stuff.)

You will notice too that your npm `dev` script is simply asking node to load the `server.js` file, which is (correctly) not mentioned anywhere in your Webpack config.

You are looking for [`babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/):

> One of the ways you can use Babel is through the require hook. The require hook will bind itself to node’s require and automatically compile files on the fly.

Create an "entry" file that first requires `babel-register` and then requires your `server.js` file:

```
// server-entry.js
require('babel-register')
require('./server.js')
```

Now change your npm `dev` script to be `node server-entry.js`.

______

Aside: it is necessary to create an entry file as `babel-register` cannot transpile the file in which it is invoked. For example, this would fail:

```
// server.js
require('babel-register')

export default function () {}
```

Comment: Alternatively, mainly for use during development, there's the `babel-node` interpreter in the [`babel-cli`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) package that can be used to directly run code that needs to be transpiled. Or create a specific Webpack configuration that uses the [`node` target](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) to bundle the server code.

Comment: I see. Why do I need to require my `server.js` file? this file is the entry file for my server side code.

Comment: @newguy You must "load" Babel's require hook before loading `server.js`, otherwise require statements cannot be intercepted by Babel and source files will not be transpiled. (You would see the same error as you are getting now.)

Comment: @sdgluck Oh you mean create another file such as `server-entry.js` and put those two lines in and run `node server-entry.js` to start the app?

Comment: @newguy Exactly :-)

Comment: @sdgluck but what should I export in my `server.js`? Will something like `export default function () {}` be enough?

Comment: @newguy You can leave your `server.js` as it is. As you have defined the `es2015` preset in your `.babelrc`, the export statements will be transpiled.