# babel-loader doesn't work for webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, babeljs

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./built/"),
        publicPath: "/built/"
    },
    plugins: [],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                options: {
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

With the above configuration,if I run **webpack**,it will get a correct result,but if I run **webpack-dev-server**,the source code in index.js will not been transpiled to ES5.In other words,babel-loader only works when **webpack**,but not **webpack-dev-server**.

why?

Comment: you need to use `babel-preset-es2015` to compile your JS to ES5, here is a link with setup https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/

Comment: certainly i  have be using that plugin,if not,how could webpack worked correctly?

Comment: Now I have push this project to github:https://github.com/zzzgit/bug_with_webpack-dev-server

Comment: the reason is that I haven't installed a local webpack-dev-server,but use the global one.

Comment: @zzzgoo Same reason for me, I'm going to add it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're missing babel-register.

`$ npm i --save-dev babel-register` and add `require('babel-register');` to the very top of your entry file (`index.js`).

See similar issue here: 
[Making export default work with Babel, webpack and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424920/making-export-default-work-with-babel-webpack-and-node-js)

Comment: I was just missing the babel-register module and did not need to add the require('babel-register'). After installing that module, the babel transform was happening correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a script like `"dev": "webpack-dev-server"` and then execute it with `npm run dev` or similar, it will execute the `webpack-dev-server` installed locally in your project's `node_modules`.

BUT if you've forgotten to add it to your project's dependencies, and you for some reason have a globally installed `webpack-dev-server`, it'll run *that* instead.

This caused the confusion described in the original question for me. The solution was, therefore, to install `webpack-dev-server` in my project with `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`.