# Babel loader doesn't work with webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to set up my webpack developer env. Below you can find my npm dependencies and scripts sections:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "http-server",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
```

and my webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');
    let webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/app.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'app.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'jshint-loader'

                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    query: {
                        presets: ["env"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            colors: true
        },
        devtool: 'source-map'
    };
```

When I run `npm run server` I got in terminal messages like below:

```
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Hash: bd3defdad89370ccb56f
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 1508ms
     Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    app.js   866 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
app.js.map  1.05 MB       0  [emitted]         main
```

But there is NO files in my output directory (`dist`). Why I have a problem like this and how can I solve it to use babel with webpack watcher?

UPDATE
Belowe you can see full output which I got after executing `webpack-dev-server`

[image]

Comment: Do you want to see the bundled files?

Comment: The bundled files are not generated at all and this is a problem

Comment: Yes that happens when you're using `webpack-dev-sever`

Comment: Try the answer I provided below

Comment: Have you tried to using `const` to require `webpack` instead of `let` and have you tried setting a `babelrc` file instead having the `query` property in your webpack config

Comment: `webpack` works fine - when I call it, it call babel, which generated all outputs and place it into `dist` directory. But `webpack-dev-server` does not call babel loader. Config is OK, because it was taken from Babel and Webpack docs

Comment: This is very weird, have you tried using `babel-register`?

Comment: But how it works when I execute `npm run build`? Babel transpile my code and save it to output directory. So looks like its not a problem with babel but with webpack-dev-server

Comment: Checkout the answer provide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396438/babel-loader-doesnt-work-for-webpack-dev-server

Comment: As @FortuneEkeruo has pointed out: When you use webpack-dev-server, no files are actually created on the file system, so this is perfectly normal. The webpack-dev-server serves the files from RAM

Comment: And how can I supooose to use Babel with  webpack watchers and get dist code?

Comment: webpack has a watch flag

Answer (score 0):

Put these three modules in your dev dependencies:

```json
{
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
  "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
}
```

And change the `.babelrc` to this:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/syntax-dynamic-import"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution for my problem was very simple and I solve it next way:
in my webpack.config.js file I add follow lines:

```
    module.exports = {
        //other options   
        ...
     watch: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        },
      ...
       //other options
```

and webpack start to watch my js code and call babel to transpile it